# Trying to code an object to spawn at a different area when colliding with the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a project I am creating a a very simple game where the player, a yellow cube, rolls around and collects a coin, a purple sphere. When the player collides or touches the coin, the coin needs to move to another part of the playing area at random, like the game snake. I also have it set up so if the player falls off the area, it resets them at the center of the area. Problem is, I cannot figure out how to get the coin to spawn at a different point. At this point, whenever the cube collides with the coin, it acts like the reset and puts the cube back at the center of the area. The first code is the reset when the cube falls off the area. The second is supposed to be the coin random spawning. I know i am supposed to add or something to the coin code but I cannot figure out what.

public class ResetTriggerPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider C)
{
    if (C.tag == "Player") {
        Transform trans = C.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform> ();
        float x = Random.Range (-10, 10);
        float z = Random.Range (-10, 10);
        trans.position = new Vector3 (0, 0.5f, 0);
    }
}
```

}

public class CoinMovementTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider C)
{
    if (C.tag == "Player") {
        Transform trans = C.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform> ();
        float x = Random.Range (-10, 10);
        float z = Random.Range (-10, 10);
        trans.position = new Vector3 (x, 0.5f, z);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you really call `OnTriggerEnter` in `CoinMovementTrigger`. Second observation - You check for Player in the if statement. I guess the coin object isn't named Player: `if (C.tag == "Player") {`